# React filter changing IDs in data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, find

I am attempting to create a simple portfolio website and am having a hard time with the portfolio item details component. I have created a list of the portfolio items as a JSON data list that will fetch assets within the app. I decided to hard-code this rather than host the data because it won't be changing too often and the artist will be updating their portfolio once or twice a year.

Here is the simple list of data in JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "img_code": "florida.jpg",
        "creation_medium": "Adobe Illustrator",
        "meta": ["graphic design", "logo", "Adobe Illustrator", "Florida Graphics & Marketing"]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "img_code": "musicapp.png",
        "creation_medium": "Adobe XD",
        "meta": ["app design", "music app", "Adobe XD", "Florida Graphics & Marketing"]
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "img_code": "dreamroom.jpg",
        "creation_medium": "Sketch for iPad Pro",
        "meta": ["hand sketch", "digital art", "Apple Sketch", "dream office"]
    },
    ...
]
```

And I am attempting to filter that list in a component to display the appropriate item on a details page. Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Data from '../data/portfolio.json';

export class PortfolioDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            itemId: this.props.location.state ? this.props.location.state.id : window.location.pathname.split('/')[2],
            portfolioItem: {}
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchPortfolioItems();
    }

    fetchPortfolioItems() {
        const data = Data.filter(item => item.id = 1);
        this.setState({portfolioItem: {data} });
    }
    
    render() {
        ....
    }

}

export default PortfolioDetails
```

However, instead of returning the one item with the id of 1, it changes every item's id to one. Here is what I am getting when I console log the results ...

```
0: {id: 1, img_code: "florida.jpg", creation_medium: "Adobe Illustrator", meta: Array(4)}
1: {id: 1, img_code: "musicapp.png", creation_medium: "Adobe XD", meta: Array(4)}
2: {id: 1, img_code: "dreamroom.jpg", creation_medium: "Sketch for iPad Pro", meta: Array(4)}
```

What am I missing? I thought this would be a simple use of the filter() method.

Comment: Inside the `.filter()` method, you are doing an assignment instead of a comparison. You need to change `item.id = 1` to `item.id == 1`

Answer (score 0):

Your code explicitly tells Javascript to assign the value of 1 to every id, and of course, 1 is truthy so it returns true to the filter function.

Change
`const data = Data.filter(item => item.id = 1);`

to

`const data = Data.filter(item => item.id == 1);`

Comment: You can help my reputation by upvoting this and marking it as the answer